# Improving the performance of a sliding-window fragment function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization

I have a script in Python 3.6.8 which reads through a very large text file, where each line is an ASCII string drawn from the alphabet `{a,b,c,d,e,f}`.

For each line, I have a function which fragments the string using a sliding window of size `k`, and then increments a fragment counter dictionary `fragment_dict` by 1 for each fragment seen.

The same `fragment_dict` is used for the entire file, and it is initialized for all possible `5^k` fragments mapping to zero.

I also ignore any fragment which has the character `c` in it. Note that `c` is uncommon, and most lines will not contain it at all.

```py
def fragment_string(mystr, fragment_dict, k):
    for i in range(len(mystr) - k + 1):

        fragment = mystr[i:i+k]
        if 'c' in fragment:
            continue

        fragment_dict[fragment] += 1
```

Because my file is so large, I would like to optimize the performance of the above function as much as possible. Could anyone provide any potential optimizations to make this function faster?

I'm worried I may be rate limited by the speed of Python loops, in which case I would need to consider dropping down into C/Cython.

Comment: @StefanPochmann the lines are generally a couple hundred characters in length, and `c` is uncommon, most lines won't have any. `k` is likely to range between 6 and 20.

Comment: @StefanPochmann it's a Python dictionary

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes the dictionary is initialized with all possible fragments mapping to 0. The alphabet size for the string is 5 not including `c`, so the number of fragments is `5^k`.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy may help in speeding up your code:

```
x = np.array([ord(c) - ord('a') for c in mystr])
filter = np.geomspace(1, 5**(k-1), k, dtype=int)
fragment_dict = collections.Counter(np.convolve(x, filter,mode='valid'))
```

The idea is, represent each k length segment is a k-digit 5-ary number. Then, converting a list of 0-5 integers equivalent to the string to its 5-ary representation is equivalent to applying a convolution with [1,5,25,125,...] as filter.

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble understanding your code, could you clarify how this matches with my original function? thanks!

Comment: This is pretty ingenious. I thought it would be faster, but unfortunately it wasn't.